# GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity error

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, active-directory, account-management

I have a .NET 3.5 method that, given a user and a list of Active Directory groups, returns the subset of groups that the user belongs to. The code works at dozens of installations, but fails at one particular customer site. The code looks like this:

```
List<GroupAttrs> ret = new List<GroupAttrs>();

foreach (SymDomainInfo domain in domains)
{
   using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain.Name, adUser, adPwd))
   {
      foreach (GroupAttrs aGroup in grpAttrs)
      {
         if (aGroup.Available)
                continue;

             GroupPrincipal pGroup;

             try
             {
                 pGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Sid, aGroup.Authid);
             }
             catch (Exception e3)
             {
                 Console.WriteLine("{3} finding group {0}/{4} in domain {1}: {2}", aGroup.Name, domain.Name, e3.Message, e3.GetType().Name, aGroup.Authid);

                 if (e3.InnerException != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("\tInner {0}: {1}", e3.InnerException.GetType().Name, e3.InnerException.Message);

                 continue;
             }

             if (pGroup != null)
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Found Group " + pGroup.DistinguishedName);
                FindUserInGroup(grpMap, identity.User, ret, pGroup);
             }
          }
   }
}
```

A `GroupAttrs` is our own database class that contains the name and SID (in the field `AuthID`) of an Active Directory group. The collection `SymDomainInfos` contains the name and paths of all the trusted domains in AD. And `adUser` and `adPassword` are the credentials of a domain user with authority to search AD.

Every iteration of the loop gives the same error:

> System.ArgumentException: Value was invalid.  Parameter name: sddlForm
>   at System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier..ctor(String sddlForm)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRefHelper(Type
>   principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime
>   referenceDate, Boolean useSidHistory)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.FindPrincipalByIdentRef(Type
>   principalType, String urnScheme, String urnValue, DateTime
>   referenceDate)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithTypeHelper(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, Nullable`1 identityType, String
>   identityValue, DateTime refDate)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.FindByIdentityWithType(PrincipalContext
>   context, Type principalType, IdentityType identityType, String
>   identityValue)
>   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext
>   context, IdentityType identityType, String identityValue)
>   at ADGroupsTest.Program.Main(String[] args)

We had one other customer for which this didn't work. The error was different, and that customer had deleted or disabled some of the default properties in Active Directory. When they restored those properties, the code began to work. So my guess is that this customer has configured their AD somehow such that `GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity` will not work when called from a domain context.

So my question is this: does anybody know what type of AD (mis)configuration would lead to this particular error? Failing that can anyone tell me what AD properties must be implemented for `FindByIdentity` to work in this case?

Comment: I just wonder, how to list all the Active Directory application groups a user belongs to? What is grpAttrs in your code? You might to add C# tag, almost otherwise nobody view your poster.

Comment: grpAttrs is a collection of database objects that correspond to the AD groups that have been "imported" into our system. AD users that are members of these groups are allowed to log into our system using the group name instead of a login and password. (Thanks for pointing out the missing C# tag.)